# How to make bundle of two configurable products?

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product, bundled-product, custom-product-type

I am developing a jewelry store in magento.
In this store mainly there are types of products:
1) Engagement Rings
2) Wedding Rings
3) Loose Diamonds

**1) Engagement Ring :**
In this there will be two configurable products Ring + Diamond.
Both Ring and Diamond will be configurable products and attributes for that are:

- **Ring** => Metal [Yello Gold, White Gold, Rose Gold, Platinum]
- **Diamond** => Color [D,E,F,G,H,I] , Shape [Circle, Square, Oval]

So, I want to allow user to select ring + diamond as in this site : [www.77diamonds.com/classic_rings.html](http://www.77diamonds.com/classic_rings.html)

so, How to add two configurable product to cart as a bundle product?

Answer (score 7):

Don't try to implement nested complex product types in Magento. I did it for a different case and it's getting ugly quite fast and you can fall in many traps. Magento is just not designed for this. Extensions that promise this should be handled with care for the same reason.

I would take a different approach, without using the configurable product at all:

#### Bundle

- **Option 1: Ring**

  - Yellow Gold Ring
  - White Gold Ring
  - Rose Gold Ring
  - Platinum Ring
- **Option 2: Diamond**

  - Circle D
  - Circle E
  - ...
  - Oval D
  - Oval E
  - ...

So basically you put all simple products of each configurable product directly into the bundle.

The rest is frontend, including JavaScript sorcery: For Option 1 nothing has to be changed, for Option 2, create two dropdowns based on the configurable attributes, then populate a hidden field with the simple product id based on the selections. You probably can reuse a good portion of the JavaScript for configurable products.

Answer (score 2):

Magento cannot add configurable products to bundled products out of the box.

You will need to either set up the simple products needed and then include the 2 items (Ring, Diamond) as separate options which are set to be required items.

Or the alternative is to either have developed or use an extension like this:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/configurable-bundle-2-0-by-wizkunde.html

Which allows you to add and configure configurable products into a bundle, but it is a paid extension.

The example you given for the 77 Diamonds site is a lot more complicated that just 2 configurable products though, that looks to be a fairly major extension of how Magento bundled products works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 1 configurable product with multiple attributes Ring Metal, Diamond Color, and Diamond Shape. The use the Magento configurable product Quick Create tool to create each of the available configurations and their respective prices. In this way you will not need to use Bundled Products.

Comment: I had tried it, but the diamonds products details are to be imported by csv which would be exported from http://diamondplatform.com/searchrecord.php?uid=1 so i thin diamond will be second configurable product. any more suggestion please?