# Product type to use when simple product can be sold either as a unit or in a case

Tags: configurable-product, products, bundled-product, simple-product

I have a situation where I have a product that fits the profile for a bundled product in that this product can either be sold in gallons (5 and 55 gal) and quarts (1 quart or a case containing 4 individual quarts).  The product has separate skus for both 5 and 55 gal but not for the quarts.  So I have this kind of situation:

## ABC Product

sku   name                qty                            price
123   ABC Product  5 gal                            $10
321   ABC Product  55 gal                        $150
456   ABC Product  1 Quart                        $50
456   ABC Product  Case (4 Quarts)        $200

Because 456 have same sku I don't have the option to use a configurable product. I know that I can use bundled product but the problem there is I can not increase the quantity for the case as it needs to be set where user can not change quantity due to 4 quarts = 1 case.

Has anyone faced this issue before or know how it can be solved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Even if this was possible if someone orders 465 from a pulldown how are you going to know which 456 they ordered?

If this were me, I would have product case SKU set to 456-CASE.

I would look at the cased product as a separate product rather than a quantity of 456's.

I do not know the reasoning for having the same SKU for a different stock item.

Comment: This has been answered previously https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37422/how-to-make-bundle-of-two-configurable-products

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jimmy sku 456 is one and the same product.  The only thing that is different are the units involved.  If it is a case that is selected from dropdown, then it would deduct 4 from the quantity of that simple product with sku 456.  If it is just a 1 unit, it would deduct 1 from simple product with sku 456.